# Getting error when change region of azure webite

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I'm using japan east region for my azure website but now i want to change region to north central us.
 I followed this link:[How to change region for Azure WebSite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11574329/how-to-change-region-for-azure-website).
I'm getting Error like this..

```
There was an error moving resources. Resources '/subscriptions/3126d3bf-1271-4e14-9898-8f05fbc50e00/resourceGroups/Default-Web-JapanEast/providers/Microsoft.Web/serverFarms/demoweb'could not be moved. The tracking Id is 'b89509bb-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-09657c7d3c93' (Code: ResourceMoveFailed) ResourceGroup contains resources and cannot be deleted without deleting the resource first. (Code: Conflict)
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Could you share more details? How you change the region? That link you provided doesn't give any details. To change your website region, you'll need to redeploy your code to a new website with the new region, check this [thead](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15312781/how-can-i-modify-the-location-of-my-web-site-in-windows-azure)

Comment: tx for replay  #forester123, so i have to make new App Service Plan with new Location for make new webapp on azure?

Comment: @MohitSolanki correct: It requires a redeploy. I marked this as duplicate of the question forester123 pointed to, since it's essentially the same question (which, coincidentally, I just discovered I posted an answer to).

Comment: tx @David Makogon..